# Main site categories that refer to pages of a subdomain

Tags: category

I have my **main** site `www.example.com` and a **subdomain** `site.example.com`

I need to make sure that from the main site, by clicking on certain categories of the menu, you are **redirected** to pages of the **subdomain** `(site.example.com)`

Are you able to do this?

With the **URLs rewrite** I can not get anything.
Thank you!